# importing xlsx with pandas: getting returns of NAN

Tags: python, excel

The i try to read an an .xlsx file, i get values of nan. 
I am actually converting an xls file to xlsx as well, but i have not posted this part of the code. Maybe this affects things. 
I need to parse this data to get the scores, but i cannot see the scores when i read the file. 
I have tried 
    data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\selenium\neww.xlsx",header=0,converters={'Priority Class':str, 1:int})
But it did not help.

The table:

```
Priority    Score Date          
This Week   100  1/24/2018                  
This Week   100  1/20/2018              
This Week   99.1 1/29/2018  


#code
url = "site"
isa_list="&org=US&to=&utf8=%E2%9C%93"
# Set full screen
browser.maximize_window()

# Allow browser to load
browser.set_page_load_timeout(60)

# Go to url
browser.get(url)

exp_btn = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((
By.XPATH, """html/body/div[4]/a""")))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", exp_btn)

# Wait for file to download
while not glob.glob(homedir + "/Downloads/*.xlsx"):
t.sleep(5)
if glob.glob(homedir + "/Downloads/*.xlsx"):
print("file downloaded")
browser.close()

# Find name of latest file downloaded
list_of_files = glob.glob(homedir + "/Downloads/*.xlsx")
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\selenium\neww.xlsx",header=0,converters={'Priority Class':str, 1:int})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

results:

```
Priority       Score                Date  
 NaN           Nan                  NaT           
 NaN           NaN                  NaT           
 This Week     100           2018-01-24           
 NaN           NaN                  NaT           
 NaN           NaN                  NaT           
 This Week     100           2018-01-20
```

Comment: Try adding `skip_blank_lines=True` to `read_excel` and see what happens?

Comment: no dice. stil says nan

Comment: Then just get rid of it: `df = df.dropna(how='all')`

Comment: for whatever reason that did not work. I did resolve the issue and ran df = df[np.isfinite(df['priority'])] - Thank you coldspeed

Comment: Sure, you can add your code as an answer then, and mark the question resolved in 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

running:

```
df = df[np.isfinite(df['SKUs'])]
```

resolved my issue with Nans. 
I only uses the rows where there is a number in the cell in column of SKUs for this code. 
Upon closer inspection the excel file had many merged cells. 
This is why other parsing methods were not working.